# When should I start applying for Tenure Track positions?

Tags: job-search, tenure-track, early-career

Ph.D. Candidate in Social Work. When should I start applying for Tenure Track positions, if I plan to complete my degree by December 2023?
I'm Canadian. And yes, there are Social Work researchers in my country.

Comment: In which country? Some countries have more of a clear timeline and "hiring seasons", others don't.

Comment: So are you looking to apply for TT jobs (typically balance of teaching, research, and service) or some sort of research job at an institute or similar?

Comment: I suggest that you start following the academic marketplace now, just to see the sorts of things that might turn up early or later. The market is generally terrible at the moment. Keep watch on it.

Comment: Yes, tenure-track jobs (teaching, research and service)

Answer (score 1):

Get organized for 2023 competitions.  These will have start dates in 2023/24.

You might have an outside shot in the 2022 cycle.  In social sciences you can get hired “just before” (or in some cases of locally known candidates even before) finishing your PhD, especially if you have teaching experience (*v.g.* as a contract lecturer).

Answer (score 0):

Generally (within the US), new faculty begin at the start of an academic year. So if you graduate in Dec 2023 you would be planning to start a faculty position in August 2024. You would apply to positions in the fall 2023 cycle. These may be posted starting in the summer or fall of 2023 and would be due in the fall of 2023 or winter of 2024.

You mention research specifically in your comments. Industry jobs (here I mean research jobs at university centers and think tanks) with little to no teaching can be posted at any time. They would be unlikely to be considered TT.

Comment: It strikes me that you are asking a very basic question, so I would recommend reading something like The Professor is In (book, not the website) to get your feet under you with regard to the job market.

Comment: Probably also depends on the country and individual university.

Comment: Right, will specify US. Within the US, Universities can vary a bit but are mostly constrained by the budget calendar so not too much.

Comment: And probably if they're predominantly research or education universities perhaps? I can't imagine the academic year being relevant when you're expected to mostly conduct research. For my university the budget year corresponds to the calendar year rather than the academic one, I assume this is common.

Comment: @MiG You should leave an answer about your area, then. In the US, 99% if not 100% of TT positions will start in the late summer.

Comment: Let's wait for the topic starter to indicate their country of interest first :)

Comment: The question is about Social Work. In my experience, there are not TT social work positions that are expected to mostly conduct research.

Comment: I already have The Professor Is In as a book.

Comment: There are social workers who do conduct research, at least in Canada.

Comment: When I say “mostly conduct research” I mean more than 90% research (teaching at most one class per year).